# Can't call open trading function

Tags: solidity, remix

So I try to call the open trading function in my code which is as follows:

```
function openTrading() external onlyOwner() {
        require(!tradingOpen,"Trading is open");
        uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D);
        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), _tTotal);
        uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(uniswapV2Router.factory()).createPair(address(this), uniswapV2Router.WETH());
        uniswapV2Router.addLiquidityETH{value: address(this).balance}(address(this),balanceOf(address(this)),0,0,owner(),block.timestamp);
        IERC20(uniswapV2Pair).approve(address(uniswapV2Router), type(uint).max);
        swapEnabled = true;
        tradingOpen = true;
    }
```

And I get the following error:

```
Transaction has been reverted by the EVM: { "blockHash": "0xa783f5ecc7bef888cf3bcd9a2aed64063333415c8a6ca867bbd6df0fe92ffbe4", "blockNumber": 4685778, "contractAddress": null, "cumulativeGasUsed": 417578, "effectiveGasPrice": 2128223284, "from": "0x9666a65844bc5eb78cac71a3452319ab53f8ab19", "gasUsed": 78359, "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "status": false, "to": "0xf17c8c7197303d8b31cd42210aded123093e8dfc", "transactionHash": "0x10a474f1dea6dbad7a5de890f83bacea3d5e593e27924e70a6b0cfc887c5845a", "transactionIndex": 1, "type": "0x2", "events": {} }
```

I assume it is a gas releated problem and I tried various different gas combinations but I just can't get it to work.

Comment: It's not a gas issue, it just can't estimate as it will fail. Check you have the correct router address and that the contract has the balances to add liquidity. If still having issues, simulate with eth_call, callTrace, or a tool like tenderly.co